# CollapsingToolbarLayout subtitle

Tags: android, android-layout, androiddesignsupport

Am I able to set the title of a [`CollapsingToolbarLayout`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/CollapsingToolbarLayout.html) via the [`setTitle`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/CollapsingToolbarLayout.html#setTitle(java.lang.CharSequence)) method?

Is there also a way to set a subtitle?

Answer (score 35):

If you want the subtitle to go to `Toolbar` when the `AppBar` is fully collapsed you should create your custom `CoordinatorLayout.Behaviour` Like this: [Github Guide](http://github.com/saulmm/CoordinatorLayoutExample)

But if you just want a smaller text behind the title when the `AppBar` is expanded you can try this layout:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">
    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="300dp"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">
        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:expandedTitleMarginBottom="160dp"
            app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="64dp"
            app:expandedTitleMarginStart="48dp"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/header"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="@drawable/quila2"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax" />
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="16sp"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:layout_marginBottom="32dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="64dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="48dp"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                android:text="Lorem Ipsum Iran Lorem Ipsum Iran Lorem Ipsum Iran Lorem Ipsum Iran Lorem Ipsum Iran Lorem Ipsum Iran Lorem Ipsum Iran Lorem Ipsum Iran "/>
            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/anim_toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />
        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scrollbars="none"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="16dp"
            android:lineSpacingExtra="8dp"
            android:text="@string/lorem"
            android:textSize="18sp"/>

    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:src="@drawable/abc_ic_search_api_mtrl_alpha"
        app:layout_anchor="@+id/appbar"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|right|end" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Notice that here I set the `AppBar` height as `300dp` and the `app:expandedTitleMarginBottom` is `160dp` so the title won't go down and conflict with the out subtitle. In this example you should set `CollapsingToolbarTitle` dynamically in the runtime with `collapsingToolbarTitle.setTitle("My Title");` method.

The result will be something like this:

[image]

Comment: You can use CollapsingToolbarLayout app:expandedTitleGravity="top" to make sure title is above TextView

Answer (score 12):

Subtitle support in a `CollapsingToolbarLayout` is a feature that I also long for, so I created a library [collapsingtoolbarlayout-subtitle](https://github.com/HendraAnggrian/collapsingtoolbarlayout-subtitle):

[image]

Use it like you would on any `CollapsingToolbarLayout`, just add subtitle attribute on it:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <com.hendraanggrian.widget.SubtitleCollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/subtitlecollapsingtoolbarlayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:contentScrim="?colorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
            app:subtitle="CollapsingToolbarLayout"
            app:title="Subtitle">

            <!-- collapsing toolbar content goes here -->

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?actionBarSize"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"/>
        </com.hendraanggrian.widget.SubtitleCollapsingToolbarLayout>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <!-- content goes here -->

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: I Really wanna use this but I can't get it to work on sdk 27

Comment: @TannerSummers it should be usable with sdk 27 `com.hendraanggrian:collapsingtoolbarlayout-subtitle:27.0.1`. See README for more.

Comment: Doesn't yet supported for latest android support library version 28.

Comment: I plan to update support library version 28 in coming days/weeks. In the meantime, AndroidX is already supported.

Comment: Error inflating com.hendraanggrian.widget.SubtitleCollapsingToolbarLayout

Answer (score 9):

Try something like [this](https://github.com/harcoPro/SubtitleCoordinatorLayoutExample), it work for me
I have created custom ViewBehavior

```
@Override
public boolean layoutDependsOn(CoordinatorLayout parent, HeaderView child, View dependency) {
    return dependency instanceof AppBarLayout;
}

@Override
public boolean onDependentViewChanged(CoordinatorLayout parent, HeaderView child, View dependency) {
    shouldInitProperties(child, dependency);

    int maxScroll = ((AppBarLayout) dependency).getTotalScrollRange();
    float percentage = Math.abs(dependency.getY()) / (float) maxScroll;

    float childPosition = dependency.getHeight()
            + dependency.getY()
            - child.getHeight()
            - (getToolbarHeight() - child.getHeight()) * percentage / 2;


    childPosition = childPosition - mStartMarginBottom * (1f - percentage);

    CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams lp = (CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams) child.getLayoutParams();
    lp.leftMargin = (int) (percentage * mEndMargintLeft) + mStartMarginLeft;
    lp.rightMargin = mMarginRight;
    child.setLayoutParams(lp);

    child.setY(childPosition);

    ...
    return true;
}
```

and this my layout

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
>


<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/app_bar_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
        >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/image"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:src="@drawable/img_nature"
            app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
            />

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
            >


            <include
                android:id="@+id/toolbar_header_view"
                layout="@layout/header_view"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/header_view_end_margin_right"
                android:visibility="gone"
                />

        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scroll"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:clipToPadding="false"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        >

      ...

    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

<include
    android:id="@+id/float_header_view"
    layout="@layout/header_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_behavior="com.subtitlebehavoir.harcopro.simple.ViewBehavior"
    />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

ViewHeader layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<com.subtitlebehavoir.harcopro.simple.HeaderView
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical"
>

<!-- Title -->
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/header_view_title"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    />

<!-- Subtitle -->
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/header_view_sub_title"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
    android:textSize="16sp"
    />


</com.subtitlebehavoir.harcopro.simple.HeaderView>
```

Comment: I'd advise adding a little extra detail, like how you included it and any options you had to pass etc.

Comment: I have made some changes so as to scale title while expanding. Find the modified version of HeaderView and ViewBehavior in my answer given below.

Comment: how do i set the title and subtitle in the center when expanded...and move to its original position when collapsed...?

Comment: Hi. Why do you need that check for SDK version inside of ViewBehavior? For me it didn't work as expected with this check.

Comment: @Harco How to change text size while scrolling?

Answer (score 5):

Here is the modified version of Harco's implmentation ([this](https://github.com/harcoPro/SubtitleCoordinatorLayoutExample)) given above which will also change the size of title as we expand and collapse the layout.

ViewBehavior.java

```
public class ViewBehavior extends CoordinatorLayout.Behavior<HeaderView> {

    private static final float MAX_SCALE = 0.5f;

    private Context mContext;

    private int mStartMarginLeft;
    private int mEndMargintLeft;
    private int mMarginRight;
    private int mStartMarginBottom;
    private boolean isHide;

    public ViewBehavior(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        mContext = context;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean layoutDependsOn(CoordinatorLayout parent, HeaderView child, View dependency) {
        return dependency instanceof AppBarLayout;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onDependentViewChanged(CoordinatorLayout parent, HeaderView child, View dependency) {
        shouldInitProperties(child, dependency);

        int maxScroll = ((AppBarLayout) dependency).getTotalScrollRange();
        float percentage = Math.abs(dependency.getY()) / (float) maxScroll;

        // Set scale for the title
        float size = ((1 - percentage) * MAX_SCALE) + 1;
        child.setScaleXTitle(size);
        child.setScaleYTitle(size);

        // Set position for the header view
        float childPosition = dependency.getHeight()
                + dependency.getY()
                - child.getHeight()
                - (getToolbarHeight() - child.getHeight()) * percentage / 2;

        childPosition = childPosition - mStartMarginBottom * (1f - percentage);

        CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams lp = (CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams) child.getLayoutParams();
        lp.leftMargin = (int) (percentage * mEndMargintLeft) + mStartMarginLeft;
        lp.rightMargin = mMarginRight;
        child.setLayoutParams(lp);

        child.setY(childPosition);

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            if (isHide && percentage < 1) {
                child.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                isHide = false;
            } else if (!isHide && percentage == 1) {
                child.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                isHide = true;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

    private void shouldInitProperties(HeaderView child, View dependency) {

        if (mStartMarginLeft == 0)
            mStartMarginLeft = mContext.getResources().getDimensionPixelOffset(R.dimen.header_view_start_margin_left);

        if (mEndMargintLeft == 0)
            mEndMargintLeft = mContext.getResources().getDimensionPixelOffset(R.dimen.header_view_end_margin_left);

        if (mStartMarginBottom == 0)
            mStartMarginBottom = mContext.getResources().getDimensionPixelOffset(R.dimen.header_view_start_margin_bottom);

        if (mMarginRight == 0)
            mMarginRight = mContext.getResources().getDimensionPixelOffset(R.dimen.header_view_end_margin_right);
    }


    public int getToolbarHeight() {
        int result = 0;
        TypedValue tv = new TypedValue();
        if (mContext.getTheme().resolveAttribute(android.R.attr.actionBarSize, tv, true)) {
            result = TypedValue.complexToDimensionPixelSize(tv.data, mContext.getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

HeaderView.java

```
public class HeaderView extends LinearLayout {

    @Bind(R.id.header_view_title)
    TextView title;

    @Bind(R.id.header_view_sub_title)
    TextView subTitle;

    public HeaderView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public HeaderView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public HeaderView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    }

    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
    public HeaderView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr, int defStyleRes) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr, defStyleRes);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onFinishInflate() {
        super.onFinishInflate();
        ButterKnife.bind(this);
    }

    public void bindTo(String title) {
        bindTo(title, "");
    }

    public void bindTo(String title, String subTitle) {
        hideOrSetText(this.title, title);
        hideOrSetText(this.subTitle, subTitle);
    }

    private void hideOrSetText(TextView tv, String text) {
        if (text == null || text.equals(""))
            tv.setVisibility(GONE);
        else
            tv.setText(text);
    }

    public void setScaleXTitle(float scaleXTitle) {
        title.setScaleX(scaleXTitle);
        title.setPivotX(0);
    }

    public void setScaleYTitle(float scaleYTitle) {
        title.setScaleY(scaleYTitle);
        title.setPivotY(30);
    }
}
```

Comment: how do i set the title and subtitle in the center when expanded...and move to its original position when collapsed...?

Comment: @HardikAmal I have modified the code to set title and subtitle at center when expended. Follow my seconds answer just posted below. Let me know if you face any issue.

Comment: it causes a blink with textviews using support lib 24.0.0 while translating from toolbar to down

Comment: is there a way to set margin for collapsed state? I have additional margin when it is collapsed because title text size increases

Answer (score 4):

I also had the same issue. In the end I made a LinearLayout that contains the title and subtitle and then set the expandedTitleTextAppearance to be transparent - effectively hiding the Toolbar title when the Layout is expanded. Using this approach the toolbar collapses over the LinearLayout and in the end only shows the title in the collapsed state.

The full xml is here:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/main_content"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/appbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/series_detail_header_height"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
    app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">
    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="64dp"
        app:expandedTitleMarginStart="48dp"
        app:expandedTitleTextAppearance="@style/TransparentText"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">
        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_collapseMode="parallax">
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/image_view"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/series_detail_header_image_height"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"/>
            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/header_text_layout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:minHeight="@dimen/series_detail_text_layout_height"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:paddingLeft="20dp"
                android:paddingRight="10dp"
                android:paddingTop="10dp">
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/title"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="My title"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                    android:textSize="24sp"/>
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/subtitle"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                    android:textSize="17sp"/>
            </LinearLayout>
        </FrameLayout>
        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="@drawable/shape_toolbar_black_gradient"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin"/>
        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:layout_gravity="top"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
            />
    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/show_view_pager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/toolbar_height"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"/></android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Make sure that your style also extends TextAppearance or the app will crash if your Design Support Library is v22.2.0 :

```
<style name="TransparentText" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance">
    <item name="android:textColor">#00666666</item>
</style>
```

This bug appears to be fixed in v22.2.1 (https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=178674):

Comment: But in this case, subtitle wont appear in collapse mode. Is there a way to achieve that ?

Comment: Sorry - but I was not able to figure out how to do that. It appears that WhatsApp has done it so it must be possible...

Comment: let us know if you have figured out how whatsapp did it

Answer (score 1):

Here is the modified version of Harco's implementation ([this](https://github.com/harcoPro/SubtitleCoordinatorLayoutExample)) with title and subtitle centred when expanded.

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">


    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/app_bar_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/image"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                android:src="@drawable/img_nature"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax" />

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin">


                <include
                    android:id="@+id/toolbar_header_view"
                    layout="@layout/header_view"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/header_view_end_margin_right"
                    android:visibility="gone" />

            </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scroll"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:clipToPadding="false"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Hello World!" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Hello World!" />

        </LinearLayout>


    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

    <include
        android:id="@+id/float_header_view"
        layout="@layout/header_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_behavior="com.subtitlebehavoir.harcopro.simple.ViewBehavior" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

dimens.xml

```
<resources>
    <!-- Default screen margins, per the Android Design guidelines. -->
    <dimen name="activity_horizontal_margin">16dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="activity_vertical_margin">16dp</dimen>

    <dimen name="header_view_end_margin_left">56dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="header_view_end_margin_right">14dp</dimen>

    <dimen name="header_view_start_margin_bottom">14dp</dimen>

</resources>
```

header_view.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<com.subtitlebehavoir.harcopro.simple.HeaderView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <!-- Title -->
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/header_view_title"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="18sp" />

    <!-- Subtitle -->
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/header_view_sub_title"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/header_view_title"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="16sp" />


</com.subtitlebehavoir.harcopro.simple.HeaderView>
```

HeaderView.java

```
public class HeaderView extends RelativeLayout {

    @Bind(R.id.header_view_title)
    TextView title;

    @Bind(R.id.header_view_sub_title)
    TextView subTitle;

    Context context;

    public HeaderView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        this.context = context;
    }

    public HeaderView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        this.context = context;
    }

    public HeaderView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
        this.context = context;
    }

    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
    public HeaderView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr, int defStyleRes) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr, defStyleRes);
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onFinishInflate() {
        super.onFinishInflate();
        ButterKnife.bind(this);
    }

    public void bindTo(String title) {
        bindTo(title, "");
    }

    public void bindTo(String title, String subTitle) {
        hideOrSetText(this.title, title);
        hideOrSetText(this.subTitle, subTitle);
    }

    private void hideOrSetText(TextView tv, String text) {
        if (text == null || text.equals(""))
            tv.setVisibility(GONE);
        else
            tv.setText(text);
    }

    public void setScaleXTitle(float scaleXTitle) {
        title.setScaleX(scaleXTitle);
        title.setPivotX(0);
    }

    public void setScaleYTitle(float scaleYTitle) {
        title.setScaleY(scaleYTitle);
        title.setPivotY(30);
    }

    public TextView getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public TextView getSubTitle() {
        return subTitle;
    }
}
```

and ViewBehavior.java

```
public class ViewBehavior extends CoordinatorLayout.Behavior<HeaderView> {

    private static final float MAX_SCALE = 0.5f;

    private Context mContext;

    private int mStartMarginLeftTitle;
    private int mStartMarginLeftSubTitle;
    private int mEndMargintLeft;
    private int mMarginRight;
    private int mStartMarginBottom;
    private boolean isHide;

    public ViewBehavior(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        mContext = context;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean layoutDependsOn(CoordinatorLayout parent, HeaderView child, View dependency) {
        return dependency instanceof AppBarLayout;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onDependentViewChanged(CoordinatorLayout parent, HeaderView child, View dependency) {
        shouldInitProperties(child, dependency);

        int maxScroll = ((AppBarLayout) dependency).getTotalScrollRange();
        float percentage = Math.abs(dependency.getY()) / (float) maxScroll;

        // Set scale for the title
        float size = ((1 - percentage) * MAX_SCALE) + 1;
        child.setScaleXTitle(size);
        child.setScaleYTitle(size);

        // Set position for the header view
        float childPosition = dependency.getHeight()
                + dependency.getY()
                - child.getHeight()
                - (getToolbarHeight() - child.getHeight()) * percentage / 2;

        childPosition = childPosition - mStartMarginBottom * (1f - percentage);
        child.setY(childPosition);

        // Set Margin for title
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lpTitle = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) child.getTitle().getLayoutParams();
        lpTitle.leftMargin = (int) ((mStartMarginLeftTitle) - (percentage * (mStartMarginLeftTitle - mEndMargintLeft)));

        if (lpTitle.leftMargin < 20) {
            lpTitle.leftMargin = 20;
        }
        lpTitle.rightMargin = mMarginRight;
        child.getTitle().setLayoutParams(lpTitle);

        // Set Margin for subtitle
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lpSubTitle = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) child.getSubTitle().getLayoutParams();
        lpSubTitle.leftMargin = (int) ((mStartMarginLeftSubTitle) - (percentage * (mStartMarginLeftSubTitle - mEndMargintLeft)));

        if (lpSubTitle.leftMargin < 20) {
            lpSubTitle.leftMargin = 20;
        }
        lpSubTitle.rightMargin = mMarginRight;
        child.getSubTitle().setLayoutParams(lpSubTitle);

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            if (isHide && percentage < 1) {
                child.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                isHide = false;
            } else if (!isHide && percentage == 1) {
                child.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                isHide = true;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

    private void shouldInitProperties(HeaderView child, View dependency) {

        if (mStartMarginLeftTitle == 0)
            mStartMarginLeftTitle = getStartMarginLeftTitle(child);

        if (mStartMarginLeftSubTitle == 0)
            mStartMarginLeftSubTitle = getStartMarginLeftSubTitle(child);

        if (mEndMargintLeft == 0)
            mEndMargintLeft = mContext.getResources().getDimensionPixelOffset(R.dimen.header_view_end_margin_left);

        if (mStartMarginBottom == 0)
            mStartMarginBottom = mContext.getResources().getDimensionPixelOffset(R.dimen.header_view_start_margin_bottom);

        if (mMarginRight == 0)
            mMarginRight = mContext.getResources().getDimensionPixelOffset(R.dimen.header_view_end_margin_right);
    }

    public int getStartMarginLeftTitle(HeaderView headerView) {
        TextView title = headerView.getTitle();
        DisplayMetrics displaymetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
        WindowManager windowManager = (WindowManager) mContext.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
        windowManager.getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displaymetrics);
        int width = displaymetrics.widthPixels;

        int stringWidth = getStingWidth(title);

        int marginLeft = (int) ((width / 2) - ((stringWidth + (stringWidth * MAX_SCALE)) / 2));
        return marginLeft;
    }

    public int getStartMarginLeftSubTitle(HeaderView headerView) {
        TextView subTitle = headerView.getSubTitle();
        DisplayMetrics displaymetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
        WindowManager windowManager = (WindowManager) mContext.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
        windowManager.getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displaymetrics);
        int width = displaymetrics.widthPixels;

        int stringWidth = getStingWidth(subTitle);

        int marginLeft = ((width / 2) - (stringWidth / 2));
        return marginLeft;
    }

    public int getStingWidth(TextView textView) {
        Rect bounds = new Rect();
        Paint textPaint = textView.getPaint();
        textPaint.getTextBounds(textView.getText().toString(), 0, textView.getText().toString().length(), bounds);
        return bounds.width();
    }

    public int getToolbarHeight() {
        int result = 0;
        TypedValue tv = new TypedValue();
        if (mContext.getTheme().resolveAttribute(android.R.attr.actionBarSize, tv, true)) {
            result = TypedValue.complexToDimensionPixelSize(tv.data, mContext.getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks its working but one problem is subtitle gravity is not center when expanded...how do i set it to center when expanded....

Comment: I am not sure about that. Will try it but it will take time.

Comment: @HardikAmal Modified the answer to make subtitle center aligned as well. Let me know if u face any problem with this.

Comment: its working...will lets you know if i face any issue...Thanks once again +1

Comment: one more query... if title or subtitle is null or empty...how do i make the other one, multilines when expanded and also align at the center of the header view

Comment: @PrashantKedia http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39073051/add-icon-with-title-in-collapsingtoolbarlayout

Comment: Hello @PrashantKedia. In general, your example works very well. But in my case, the title and subTitle are obtained remotely through a request using Volley in OnCreate of my activity. This causes the getStingWidth () method ViewBehavior always returns 0, since the textView.getText () returns empty. Consequently the center alignment of title and subtitle does not occur. Do you have any idea how to get around this problem?? I really need this to work. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

i managed to make it using MotionLayout in your activity.xml make the following

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.motion.widget.MotionLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
app:layoutDescription="@xml/motion_scene_collapsing_toolbar_with_subtitle"
tools:context=".CollapsingToolbarWithSubtitleActivity">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/toolbar_image_expanded"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    android:contentDescription="@null"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
    android:src="@drawable/img1" />
<!--    transformPivotX and transformPivotY is to move text horizontal
or vertical in it's own boundaries when the text is smaller than it's boundaries-->
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/toolbar_title"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="This is title"
    android:textColor="@color/white"
    android:textSize="30sp"
    android:transformPivotX="0sp"
    android:transformPivotY="25sp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/toolbar_sub_title"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="start"
    android:text="This is sub title"
    android:textColor="@color/white"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:transformPivotX="6sp"
    android:transformPivotY="0sp" />

<!--    you can put any thing here ex (RecyclerView or Image or .... any thing).-->
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv_remaining_body"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="remaining body what ever it is"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/toolbar_image_expanded" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.motion.widget.MotionLayout>
```

and then for @xml/motion_scene_collapsing_toolbar_with_subtitle add the following

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<MotionScene xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
<ConstraintSet android:id="@+id/expanded">
    <Constraint
        android:id="@+id/toolbar_image_expanded"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">
        <CustomAttribute
            app:attributeName="imageAlpha"
            app:customIntegerValue="255" />
    </Constraint>

    <Constraint
        android:id="@+id/toolbar_title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="42dp"
        android:scaleX="1.0"
        android:scaleY="1.0"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/toolbar_image_expanded"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

    <Constraint
        android:id="@+id/toolbar_sub_title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scaleX="1.0"
        android:scaleY="1.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/toolbar_title"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/toolbar_title" />
</ConstraintSet>

<ConstraintSet android:id="@+id/collapsed">
    <Constraint
        android:id="@+id/toolbar_image_expanded"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">
        <CustomAttribute
            app:attributeName="imageAlpha"
            app:customIntegerValue="0" />
    </Constraint>

    <Constraint
        android:id="@+id/toolbar_title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
        android:scaleX="0.7"
        android:scaleY="0.7"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/toolbar_image_expanded" />

    <Constraint
        android:id="@+id/toolbar_sub_title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scaleX="0.7"
        android:scaleY="0.7"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/toolbar_image_expanded"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/toolbar_title"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/toolbar_title" />
</ConstraintSet>

<Transition
    app:constraintSetEnd="@id/collapsed"
    app:constraintSetStart="@id/expanded">
    <OnSwipe
        app:dragDirection="dragUp"
        app:touchAnchorId="@id/tv_remaining_body"
        app:touchAnchorSide="top" />
</Transition>
</MotionScene>
```

and if you want to know more about MotionLayout
visit this https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/motion-layout/#0