# CollapsingToolbarLayout info covering title

Tags: android, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

Anybody know how to add info below the title when using a CollapsingToolbarLayout?

I'm setting the title using mCollapsingToolbarLayout.setTitle(myTitle), which you can see works in the screenshot.  In the layout, I'm also setting some other things (ratings and category).  As you can see, the title is behind that extra info.  Anybody know of a nice way to fix this?  Thank you!

Screen shot:
[image]

Here's my layout file:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="?attr/background">
<!-- The main content view -->

<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    android:id="@+id/coordinator_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:collapsedTitleTextAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.Widget.AppCompat.Toolbar.Title"
            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/iv_detailHeaderImage"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
                app:layout_collapseParallaxMultiplier="1.0" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
                android:gravity="bottom"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tv_detailCategory"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:paddingEnd="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                    android:paddingStart="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                    android:text="category"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/abc_text_size_small_material"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />


                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                    android:gravity="start|center_vertical"
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:paddingEnd="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                    android:paddingStart="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/tv_detailRatingNumber"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/abc_text_size_small_material" />

                    <RatingBar
                        android:id="@+id/rb_detailRatingBarStars"
                        style="?android:attr/ratingBarStyleIndicator"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                        android:numStars="5"
                        android:progressDrawable="@drawable/rating_star_white"
                        android:stepSize="0.1" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/tv_detailRatingAmount"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/abc_text_size_small_material" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/tv_detailRatingBarDollars"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/abc_text_size_small_material" />

                </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?actionBarSize"
                android:gravity="bottom"
                android:paddingEnd="0dp"
                android:paddingLeft="8dp"
                android:paddingRight="0dp"
                android:paddingStart="8dp"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin" />
        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:id="@+id/nsv_detailScrollView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

        <include
            android:id="@+id/ll_detailParent"
            layout="@layout/venue_detail_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

<!-- The drawer content view -->
<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/nv_nav_drawer_main"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/drawer_list_header"
    app:menu="@menu/drawer_items" />
```

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue and posted the code I used to fix it here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/31529101/834692

Hopefully you might also find this useful. Good luck!