# It is possible to place a TextView below the Title of CollapsingToolbarLayout?

Tags: android-layout, material-design

It is possible to make a TextView floating down the Title of CollapsingToolbarLayout when it expanded?

Comment: This answers my question
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31194280/collapsingtoolbarlayout-subtitle/31529101#31529101