# How I can multiline the expanded title of CollapsingToolbarLayout?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout, android-design-library

My problem is the next. I would use relatively large texts as CollapsingToolbarLayout title so I need to show it as multiline mode. When I try to change text appearance through the `setExpandedTitleTextAppearance()` method it doesn't work. The code who I used is the next:

```
<style name="ToolbarExpandedTitle">
    <item name="android:textSize">48sp</item>
    <item name="android:shadowColor">#ffffff</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@android:color/white</item>
    <item name="android:singleLine">false</item>
    <item name="android:minLines">3</item>
    <item name="android:lines">4</item>
    <item name="android:maxLines">5</item>
</style>
```

[image]

**I would like to see the title on multiple lines instead of showing the ellipsis.**

Comment: Solved it? I would like to know the answer, thanks.

Answer (score 24):

With the release of new Material Design 1.2.0-alpha05 this feature is implemented as a native function.

implement material library with version after(1.2.0-alpha05):

```
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.2.0-alpha05'
```

Add this line to XML of Collapsing Toolbar Layout (this example I set 2 lines as max)

```
app:maxLines="2"
```

Alternatively you can set it programmatically

```
 collapsingtoolbar.setMaxLines(2);
```

Comment: I noticed that if you set `app:maxLines="2"` then `expandedTitleGravity` attribute doesn't seem to work anymore, and I can't center the text

Answer (score 18):

Checkout this library [multiline-collapsingtoolbar](https://github.com/opacapp/multiline-collapsingtoolbar).

> multiline-collapsingtoolbar is a replacement for
>   CollapsingToolbarLayout from the Android Design Support Library which
>   can deal with multiline titles (currently hard-coded to a maximum of 3
>   lines) in the expanded state. When collapsing the toolbar, the lower
>   lines of the title fade away to leave only the top line visible.

As the Design Support Library, it should be compatible with API 7 (Android 2.1) and above

Comment: The second option does not provide any help... Could you please update your answer?

Comment: @MinasMina that will but not in all case

Answer (score 5):

This doesn't seem to be supported at present. A possible workaround is to use your own view and hide the toolbar title when expanded. One approach to do this is here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/31529101/834692

Hopefully a future version of the Support Library will add this.

Answer (score 4):

I did this with help from this library

https://github.com/opacapp/multiline-collapsingtoolbar

add the library to your project 
and replace the `CollapsingToolbarLayout` with `net.opacapp.multilinecollapsingtoolbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout`

Answer (score 4):

A simpler approach would be to add a custom layout added to the CollapsingToolbar and pin it.

Some of the notes to take care:

- The the toolbar should have the height of your collapsed content, this can be done by code or at the XML.
- The elements you want to hide must be BEFORE the toolbar definition in the layout XML file
- The elements you want to remain visible must be AFTER the toolbar definition in the layout XML file.

Checkout the full code [here](https://github.com/JavierSP1209/PinnedToolbar). The final result is:

[image: Multiline toolbar]