# Multiline expanded title in CollapsingToolbarLayout Android?

Tags: android, android-coordinatorlayout, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

How it is possible to make multiline title in `CollapsingToolbarLayout` like..
whatsapp

[image]

**My XML file**

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/main_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/detail_backdrop_height"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">


        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="16dp"
            app:expandedTitleMarginStart="16dp"
            app:expandedTitleTextAppearance="@style/HeaderTitleStyle"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">


                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/cover_image"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"                             android:layout_height="@dimen/detail_backdrop_height"
                        android:background="@color/white"
                        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                        android:scaleType="fitXY"
                        android:src="@drawable/default_clg_image"
                        app:layout_collapseMode="parallax" />


            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

**expandedTitleTextAppearance**

```
app:expandedTitleTextAppearance="@style/HeaderTitleStyle"
```

**This is my style.xml**

```
<style name="HeaderTitleStyle" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance">
    <item name="android:textColor">#FFFFFF</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">20sp</item>
    <item name="android:singleLine">false</item>
</style>
```

Comment: no, still i searching for this.

Comment: Have you found any solution for this ?

Comment: no @VishalPatoliyaツ

Comment: Anyway i have found the solution like we can assign max lines in collapsible toolbar along with app bar height.

Comment: Good @VishalPatoliyaツ thanks for inform.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found an awesome library named [**multiline-collapsingtoolbar**](https://github.com/opacapp/multiline-collapsingtoolbar), which gives you a custom collapsing toolbar that can deal with multiline titles.

> ### Usage
>
> The library's public API is identical to the version from the support library, so you can use it as a drop-in replacement.
>
> As the Design Support Library, it should be compatible with API 7
>   (Android 2.1) and above.
>
> XML layout example:
>
> ```
> <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
>         android:layout_height="192dp"
>         android:layout_width="match_parent">
>     <net.opacapp.multilinecollapsingtoolbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout
>             android:layout_width="match_parent"
>             android:layout_height="match_parent"
>             app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">
>         <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
>                 android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
>                 android:layout_width="match_parent"
>                 app:layout_collapseMode="pin"/>
>     </net.opacapp.multilinecollapsingtoolbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
> </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
> ```
>
> You can find a simple demo application in the `demo` module.

Answer (score 0):

A simpler approach could be add a custom layout to your Collapsing toolbar and pin it when collapsing, this could be the final output: [image]

Please take a look on my previews [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43161708/1345391) about this to see the full code