# Disable CollapsingToolbarLayout elevation

Tags: android, material-design, toolbar, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

I'm using code from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32220854/1567541). And I'm trying to disable the elevation of the toolbar when collapsed. I tried putting `android:elevation="0dp"` to all xml tags but it just didn't work out. Any suggestion?

[image]

Comment: Target Api >=21 or <21 ? Take a look here :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26575197/no-shadow-by-default-on-toolbar

Comment: holy bejesus using app:elevation instead of android:elevation actually works. Why did you remove your comment? Please post it as an answer

Comment: Hi Hendra, Did you ever got to solve this? I've tried setting app:elevation="0dp" in the collapsingToolbarLayout but it doesn't seem to have any effect

Comment: @Nemesis you're not supposed to put app:elevation on CollapsingToolbarLayout, it is not the one who actually have an elevation attribute. You put it in AppBarLayout, which is a direct parent of CollapsingToolbarLayout. Let me know how it works for you or if you need an example code.

Comment: @HendraAnggrian great! That solved the issue, I don't know how I didn't come up with this earlier, now it seems so obvious.

Comment: @Nemesis no worries, happy coding!

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Setting `app:elevation="0dp"` on `AppBarLayout` does the job.

Comment: Thank you so much.

Comment: That's it! Thank you dude!

Comment: Those who tried and did not work - make sure you use `app` annotation and not `android`

Answer (score 4):

Just add

```
android:stateListAnimator="@null"
```

to your `AppBarLayout`